# Adding second attribute into product detail description tab via Layout

Tags: layout, magento2.2.2

I am attempting to add a second attribute into the Details tab on a product description page, but I have been unable to make it work. Here is the code that I am trying within my `catalog_product_view.xml` file (which is working). I am attempting to do it through the custom template file listed in the code below.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="included.package" after="-"  template="Gl_Experience::included.phtml" /> 
</referenceBlock>
```

I have validated that this block works if I reference a block other than `product.info.description`.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add additional tab on product view page and want to show custom attribute value ?

Comment: Nope, I have additional tabs added in already, that is working correct. I want to add an additional block of content below the `description` field on the details tab.